# Why don't for..of loops over Iterables work when run within Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
const myMap = new Map([["name", 5]]);
for (const foo of myMap.values()) {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

When I run this code in node (v8.12.0) directly, it works and prints out "5" to console.

If I run this exact same code in a Jest test, it never executes the contents of the for loop. It runs the for condition and then just skips past the loop, never actually enumerating the values.

Why is that?  Is there something about the JS runtime used by Jest (isn't it node?) that doesn't support for..of over iterables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a very long investigation, I have gotten to the bottom of this. Important background information about the solution:

1. When targeting older ECMAscript versions like ES3 and ES5 with the TypeScript compiler, using `for..of` loops to iterate over `Iterable` collections is not supported by default. If you want to use `for..of` with `Iterable`, you have to either target something newer than ES5 or use the [`--downlevelIteration flag`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#new---downleveliteration).
2. To use Jest with a TypeScript project, you use [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/). At least, I was. I think you can also use babel somehow but I think ts-jest is [preferred](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/babel7-or-ts).
3. When using ts-jest, by default it tries to use the tsconfig.json file that the project uses -- which, as far as I can tell, means the one that is next to the jest.config.js file you are using (or the current directory if you aren't specifying a jest.config.js file). If it cannot find a tsconfig.json file in the project directory, it uses the default TypeScript compiler options. The default compiler options cause the TypeScript compiler to target ES3 or ES5 (the [ts-jest docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/tsconfig) claim it defaults to ES3 but that ts-jest overrides the default in this case to be ES5). `--downlevelIteration` is not on by default.

With all this in mind, I was able to figure out that ts-jest was not able to find my project's tsconfig.json file and so it was running my tests using the default settings, which meant targeting ES5 and not allowing `downlevelIteration`, so all my `for..of` loops over `Iterable` didn't work. The reason it couldn't find my tsconfig.json file is because my jest.config.js file was in a different directory (higher up in the tree) and even though I was running jest from a directory with a tsconfig.json file, ts-jest was not looking in the "current" directory but was instead looking in the directory that I pointed jest at for my jest.config.js file, which did not contain a tsconfig.json.

My solution to this was to rework my directory structure a bit and leverage [the tsConfig option](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/tsconfig) of ts-jest to tell it where to find my tsconfig.json file, which made everything "magically" work since my tsconfig.json file targets es2018, which supports `for..of` iteration over `Iterable`.

One alternative solution I considered but quickly disregarded was feature of the aforementioned tsConfig setting to directly set the `--downlevelIteration` compiler option in the jest config. I chose not to do that because, while it would have fixed this specific problem, it would not have fixed the larger problem which is that my Jest tests were compiling my TypeScript with different flags than my production code! It just so happens that only current problem caused by this was my `for..of` loop misery.

A quick postscript: the way I eventually made headway on this issue is by stumbling across the [diagnostics option](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/diagnostics) in ts-jest. Once I set it to true, when I tried to run my tests, an error like this was displayed:

`TypeScript diagnostics (customize using [jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics option): src/foo.ts:163:47 - error TS2569: Type 'Map<Guid, FooInfo>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`

It seems like TS compiler errors should be displayed (and cause test failures) regardless of whether or not ts-jest "diagnostics" are enabled but *shrug*.